# How do I monitor network traffic for IPP (LPD/LPR)?

Tags: networking, network-printer, wireshark, traffic, lpr

I'm writing an application that sends print jobs over IPP to an LPR print server. I need a way to monitor the traffic going between that server and my development box. Right now I'm just sending jobs from the command line with the `lpr` command.

I've tried setting up Wireshark, but I can't find anything at all going to the IP address of the print server. Besides that, the Wireshark output is a little overwhelming, as I'm not sure what protocols I need to be paying attention to for IPP traffic.

What protocols do I need to be watching? Are there caveats of which I should be aware?

Comment: LPR? Are you sure you don't mean CUPS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using CUPS, both through various GUI elements in Mac OS X, as well as through the `lpr` command (where the network printer is the default).

Comment: `lpr` is a (client) command to send jobs off to a server. There is no such thing as an *LPR print server*. There are LPD print servers however... If you send via IPP, that would make the target an *IPP print server*. The CUPS commandline named `lpr` does speak IPP when you send off a job. On Windows there is an equally-named `lpr` client command (for the cmd window), but it does speak the "LPD" protocol, not IPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPP is HTTP over port 631.

Comment: Thanks! Just for historical purposes I'll include this link: http://wiki.wireshark.org/IPP. You can also filter with `ipp` without having to specify the port at all.

Comment: That's because `ipp` *is* the port, as given by `/etc/services`.

Comment: It's only the **transport** part of IPP that is taken from HTTP. The rest isn't. IPP is a protocol of its own.

Answer (score 1):

IPP as a standard uses port 631.

If your print server is CUPS, watch out for TCP as well as UDP. Also, in your cupsd.conf you could have an admin switched to a different port for IPP.

Windows also can pose as an IPP print server. But Microsoft supports IPP/1.0 only (which never became a Standard on the IETF, 1.0 always remained a Draft -- the first official standard was IPP/1.1). And Microsoft uses port 80, not 631.